# Can I be in my room alone with my cousin female me male?

Tags: quran, hadith, sunnah, muslim-practices, shaitan

Salam, we are both muslim, I am a guy and she is a girl, they come twice a year to our house, she is my cousin. I was wondering if it is permissible to have her in my room just me and her with the door open we just want to talk and play things and there are people around the house. I know of the sunnah that shaatan will be a 3rd but since we are having the door open and people are still around the house is this okay?

Comment: So, you want to follow Shaitan anyway? He is forcing you to find a loophole.

Comment: We really just want to talk and be friends though no intention of anything like this

Comment: You already possess the knowledge that when a male and a female are alone the third companion is Shaitan. This means Shaitan will eventually seduce them. Despite this knowledge you want to persist on what Shaitan is putting into your heart.

Comment: Shaitan is your open enemy. Read [Quran 35:6](https://quran.com/35/6). It is forbidden to you to remain with your female cousin alone in your room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intermingling is a means of much evil and great corruption, and it it is not permissible. Islamic Shari’ah, which is the legislation of Allāh (سبحانه و تعالى), came to bring about all forms of benefits. It also came to remove all types of harm and corruption. Therefore, there is no doubt that free-mixing between the sexes is a huge door towards evil. It is a key that opens up all types of tribulations within society.

> Prophet [ﷺ] said, “Command your children to pray at the age of seven,
> and smack them if they don’t pray at the age of ten. And separate
> their beds (i.e. at the age of ten)”. [Abu Dawood 495]

He [i.e. the Messenger] commanded that their beds are separated, because the proximity of one of them to the other at the age of ten and beyond is a means of indecency due to intermingling between boys and girls, and there is no doubt that having them together in the primary stage every day is a means to that as it is a means to intermingling in later stages.